# Cleaner way and alternative to write if and else with JS checks

Tags: javascript

What are some alternatives to write cleaner, better, and smarter if/else function?

I am actually trying to convert my code to something more readable.

```
 const statusComment = () => {
      const isApproved = "";
      const unApproved = "";

      let status;

      // is approved and has comment.
      if (checkApproval && comment) {
        status = `${isApproved}  — ${comment}`;
        // is not approved and has comment.
      } else if (!checkApproval && comment) {
        status = `${unApproved}  — ${comment}`;
        // has comment.
      } else if (comment) {
        status = comment;
        // is approved.
      } else if (checkApproval) {
        status = isApproved;
      } else {
        // is not approved.
        status = unApproved;
      }

      return status;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down a bit: your string has two parts that are joined by a dash `-`:

1. The first part is always present: it depends on the `checkApproval` boolean value.
2. The second part is optional and depends on the truthy status of `comment`.

Also, do note that your third statement is not possible to get to, since `comment` is always truthy in the first two statements and it's combined with a boolean flag.

Therefore, you can create an array with the compulsory first part with this ternary statement:

```
const status = [checkApproval ? "" : ""];
```

For the second optional part, you push into it when `comment` is truthy:

```
if (comment) status.push(comment);
```

Here's your modified code:

```
const statusComment = () => {
  const status = [checkApproval ? "" : ""];
  if (comment) status.push(comment);

  return status.join(' — ');
};
```

Comment: That's very clean! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a table based on your existing code:

```
checkApproval     comment        out
true              true           green - comment
false             true           red - comment
                  true           comment         duplicate/unnecessary?
true                             green
false                            red
```

So we see that if there is true for checkApproval, it's green, and red otherwise.

Let's make that right now:

```js
const status = `${checkApproval ? "" : ""}`;
```

And if there's a comment, there is a dash followed by the comment.
This we can represent too:

```js
const status = `${checkApproval ? "" : ""}${comment ? " - " + comment : ""}`;
```

If there is no comment, nothing is added after.

Then we can just return `status` normally.